# How to install whole folder to user Documents folder using inno setup compiler?

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to create a folder which contains some documents of the setup under the `User Documents` folder. I am getting the error

> No files found matching %path%.

This is what I have tried:

```
[Files]

Source: "C:\Users\abc\source\repos\def\dashboard\Examples\*"; DestDir: "{userdocs}\Examples"
```

Comment: You probably need to create the folder using the `[Dirs]` section.

Comment: Keep in mind that this would only install the files for the current user. (Other users that log on would not have those files installed.)

Comment: The error means that there are no files like `C:\Users\abc\source\repos\def\dashboard\Examples\*` on the machine, where you are compiling the installer. Maybe there are a files, but in subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

In `destdir` write `{userdocs}` and in `source` supply the path of file or folder, not its destination and I would recommend you put your files in a simpler path.

Code

```
Source:c:/myfiles/myfolder*;destdir:{userdocs}
```